# Bootstrap css center nested div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm havent been front end coding for quite a while, havent been coding at all for quite a while. Now i'm trying some things again and i'm kinda stuck at something and hoping you folks could help me out :)

I've got a bootstrap row with nested divs. I want to center align the nested div's but can't seem to figure out how. Is there anyone able to push me in the right direction? My code is as follows:

```
<!--Features block Start-->
<div class="row">
<div id="features" class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-3 features-content"><img class="center" src="img/icons/ssd.png" alt="ssd"><h3 class="center">SSD.</h3><p class="center">Placeholder text.</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 features-content"><img class="center" src="img/icons/network.png" alt="network"><h3 class="center">Network.</h3><p class="center">Place holder text</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 features-content"><img class="center" src="img/icons/database.png" alt="database"><h3 class="center">Database.</h3><p class="center">Placeholder text.</p></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row features-content"> 
        <div class="col-sm-3 features-content"><img class="center" src="img/icons/opensource.png" alt="ssd"><h3 class="center">We <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart heart-color"></span> Open Source.</h3><p class="center">Placeholder text.</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 features-content"><img class="center" src="img/icons/cpanel.png" alt="network"><h3 class="center">CPanel.</h3><p class="center">Placeholder text.</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 features-content"><img class="center" src="img/icons/support.png" alt="database"><h3 class="center">24/7 Support.</h3><p class="center">Placeholder text.</p></div>
    </div>               
</div>
</div>
<!--Features block Stop-->
```

with the following CSS

```
#features{
background-color:#e1dbc5;
position: relative;
}
#features-content{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

which results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocbjw.png

Anyone able to shed some light on this for me? If there is anything unclear or you need more information from me please ask!

Kind regards,
Arjen.

Comment: Check this! http://jsfiddle.net/s8b74L1x/

Comment: width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;   
    margin: auto;

Comment: Check the Bootstrap doc here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#features-content{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
#features{
background-color:#e1dbc5;
position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

text-align center on both ID's

Answer (score 1):

actually it is much easier if you use the default grid for more nesting to get your design right

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="features" class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-4 features-content">
                <img class="center" src="img/icons/ssd.png" alt="ssd">
                <h3 class="center">SSD.</h3>
                <p class="center">Placeholder text.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 features-content">
                <img class="center" src="img/icons/network.png" alt="network">
                <h3 class="center">Network.</h3>
                <p class="center">Place holder text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 features-content">
                <img class="center" src="img/icons/database.png" alt="database">
                <h3 class="center">Database.</h3>
                <p class="center">Placeholder text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="row features-content" style="text-align:center;"> 
            <div class="col-sm-4 features-content">
                <img class="center" src="img/icons/opensource.png" alt="ssd">
                <h3 class="center">We <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart heart-color"></span> Open Source.</h3>
                <p class="center">Placeholder text.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 features-content">
                <img class="center" src="img/icons/cpanel.png" alt="network">
                <h3 class="center">CPanel.</h3>
                <p class="center">Placeholder text.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 features-content">
                <img class="center" src="img/icons/support.png" alt="database">
                <h3 class="center">24/7 Support.</h3>
                <p class="center">Placeholder text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>               
    </div>
</div>
```

[check this](http://www.bootply.com/e422bV5pOV)

Comment: Jup, thanks for you help. Was thinking way too hard. Since i'm already aligning the image and paragraph, just using the default grid layout sorted it out ( was using 3x3 which needed to be 3x4 ) Thank you all for your help <3